# How do some subdomains have the same domain authority as their main site?

Tags: seo, wordpress, subdomain, domain-authority

I was wondering how can some sub domains have the same domain authority with main site? for example`aws.amazon.com` have the same domain authority with `amazon.com` but a blog made by `wordpress.com` like `user.wordpress.com`  which is a sub domain of `wordpress.com` doesn't have the same domain authority with `wordpress.com`.

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters! While for sub-domains some metrics are inherited from the domain, authority is based upon many metrics that each site must earn. Cheers!!

Comment: Domain authority as measured by who?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller moz.com

Answer (score 1):

Google views subdomains as separate websites, and as such they're ranked separately. As @closetnoc pointed out above, in the eyes of search engines, the subdomains have their own ladder to climb.

Some companies have strategically used subdomains to dominate the SERPs. If your main domain ranks #1 for a certain search query, and your subdomain ranks #2, you can better dominate the first page. But I digress.

In this case, AWS is a full Amazon suite of products and services that's very popular on its own, and also a separate entity from, say, Amazon Music, or Amazon Marketplace proper. This allows Amazon to keep the branding, look, and feel of the site while having separate websites for two very different things. The subdomain is every bit as trusted a website as the original site itself.

"User" is not a WordPress product. Have you seen that page? It's not even active at this point. It's some guy's blog, which he left for Medium some time ago.

In the WordPress.com structure, your blog URL, unless you registered your own domain and pointed WP.com there, is `blog-name.wordpress.com` and it seems like this guy just registered "User" as his blog name, but didn't point it at a web domain host, choosing to leave the default (free) version of the URL.